# Variable 'myCellChoice' was never mutated inside if statement in didSelectRowAt indexPath function

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I have the function didSelectRowAt indexPath with an if statement inside.

myButtonChoiceString2 successfully passes the String title.text of the button selected from a previous view controller.

When removing the if else statement the code works but am only able then to display back workouts so have included this if else to allow shoulder workouts to be shown.

Please can you see what i am doing wrong with the if else to be getting these warnings:

- First Warning : Variable 'myCellChoice' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant
- Second Warning : Initialization of immutable value 'myCellChoice' was never used
- Third Warning : Initialization of immutable value 'myCellChoice' was never used

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      //First Warning Below
      var myCellChoice = DataService.instance.backWorkouts[indexPath.row]

      if myButtonChoiceString2 == "BACK" {
          //Second Warning Below
          let myCellChoice = DataService.instance.backWorkouts[indexPath.row]
      } else if myButtonChoiceString2 == "SHOULDERS" {
          //Third Warning Below
          let myCellChoice = DataService.instance.shoulderWorkouts[indexPath.row]
      }

      videoPlayer.loadVideoID(myCellChoice.videoCode)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the warning for the first var because it should be declared as **let** not **var** because on the method you never assigned a value to it so it's constant not variable , regarding the other 2 warnings both are declared inside **if----else** statement where both of them not being used , actually the line

```
 videoPlayer.loadVideoID(myCellChoice.videoCode)
```

reads the `myCellChoice` the var declared at most-top , this one

```
 var myCellChoice = DataService.instance.backWorkouts[indexPath.row]
```

not the ones declared inside the **if-----else** statements , so both of them from the logic of the compiler are **useless**

**All** should be re-written like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      if myButtonChoiceString2 == "BACK" {

            let myCellChoice = DataService.instance.backWorkouts[indexPath.row]

            videoPlayer.loadVideoID(myCellChoice.videoCode)

        } else if myButtonChoiceString2 == "SHOULDERS" {

            let myCellChoice = DataService.instance.shoulderWorkouts[indexPath.row]

            videoPlayer.loadVideoID(myCellChoice.videoCode)

      }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant Thank you! This works, i think the main issue i was facing was leaving the videoPlayer.loadVideoID(myCellChoice.videoCode) outside of the if statement. Cheers